# Pandas - merge two dataframes, sum similar columns, only keep rows with matching keys (inner join)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm stuck between pandas `concat` and `merge` function, struggling to get the best of both. I need to inner-join the rows on name and date, summing common columns A and B, and keep the value from category (really I could add this to the join if needed, they match).

Example-

df1

```
| name | date     | A | B | category |
|------|----------|---|---|----------|
| W    | 1/1/2020 | 1 | 1 | home     |
| W    | 1/2/2020 | 1 | 1 | home     |
| Y    | 1/3/2020 | 1 | 1 | garden   |
| Y    | 1/4/2020 | 1 | 1 | garden   |
```

df2

```
| name | date     | A | B | category |
|------|----------|---|---|----------|
| W    | 1/1/2020 | 2 | 2 | home     |
| W    | 1/2/2020 | 1 | 1 | home     |
| Y    | 1/3/2020 | 1 | 1 | garden   |
| Y    | 1/5/2020 | 1 | 1 | garden   |
```

desired result -

```
| name | date     | A | B | category |
|------|----------|---|---|----------|
| W    | 1/1/2020 | 3 | 3 | home     |
| W    | 1/2/2020 | 2 | 2 | home     |
| Y    | 1/3/2020 | 2 | 2 | garden   |
```

I've found that `merge` will join the rows, but duplicates any columns not joined on instead of summing them.

`concat` will sum the rows, but doesn't do an inner join so I get rows with data from just one dataframe or the other. I've tried `pd.concat([df_1, df_2], join='inner'`, but the "inner" doesn't do what I want.

Comment: I would say use a `groupby` on `date` and `category`, and `sum(A)`, `sum(B)` as your aggregates.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a groupby on `name`, `date`, and `category`, with a `sum` aggregate (to sum on `A` and `B`). This gives extra columns though, as the rows with the dates `1/4/2020` and `1/5/2020` just don't disappear, but are summed at 1.

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['W', 'W', 'Y', 'Y'], 
                   'date': ['1/1/2020', '1/2/2020', '1/3/2020', '1/4/2020 '],
                   'A': [1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'B': [1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'category': ['home', 'home', 'garden', 'garden']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['W', 'W', 'Y', 'Y'], 
                   'date': ['1/1/2020', '1/2/2020', '1/3/2020', '1/5/2020 '],
                   'A': [2, 1, 1, 1],
                   'B': [2, 1, 1, 1],
                   'category': ['home', 'home', 'garden', 'garden']})

df3 = pd.concat([df, df2]).groupby(by=['name', 'date', 'category']).sum()
```

This gives you:

```
                         A  B
name date      category      
W    1/1/2020  home      3  3
     1/2/2020  home      2  2
Y    1/3/2020  garden    2  2
     1/4/2020  garden    1  1
     1/5/2020  garden    1  1
```

You can then filter on the values of `A` or/and `B` if you don't want to see rows with a sum = 1

Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree, `append()` + `groupby()` is the best way to go, but he doesn't want to keep anything from df2 if there's not a name-date match on df1.  Could probably just do a quick left merge on df1 after you get your result.

Answer (score 0):

First "naive" solution:

```
d3 = pd.merge(d1,d2, left_on = ["name","date","category"], right_on = ["name","date","category"])
d3 = d3.assign(A = d3.A_x + d3.A_y, B = d3.B_x + d3.B_y, ).drop(columns=["A_y","A_x","B_y","B_x"])
```

Better solution, no need to manualy adding columns:

```
key = ["name","date","category"]
d3 = pd.merge(d1,d2, left_on = key, right_on = key)[key]
d4 = pd.concat([d1, d2]).groupby(by=key).sum()
d5 = pd.merge(d3,d4,right_on = key, left_on = key)
```

Result:

```
     name        date    category  A  B
0   W       1/1/2020    home       3  3
1   W       1/2/2020    home       2  2
2   Y       1/3/2020    garden     2  2
```

Using `pd.merge` You can specify composite key `["name","date","category"]` joining 2 dataframes.

Comment: I did end up doing something like this, but I'll keep the question open in case there's a solution that doesn't involve manually summing/renaming columns. I had 6 common columns in my data sets so I had to sum and drop 12 columns which gets tedious.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```py
dff = df1
    .set_index(['name', 'date', 'category'])
    .add(df2.set_index(['name', 'date', 'category'])
    .reset_index()
    .dropna()
    .reindex(columns=df1.columns)

dff
```

Output:

```
    name    date    A   B   category
 0  W   1/1/2020    3   3   home
 1  W   1/2/2020    2   2   home
 2  Y   1/3/2020    2   2   garden
```

This is what you want?

Comment: Close, but result is 3 rows only.